# Difference between free and available RAM

Tags: ram, free

What is the difference between `free` and `avaible` RAM when I use the command `free -m`?

If I have several virtual machines running on my host it shows me that I have just 200MB free and 3.8GB available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `man free`

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html :

- free:   Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)
- available:
  Estimation of how much memory is available for  starting  new
  applications,  without  swapping. Unlike the data provided by
  the cache or free fields, this field takes into account  page
  cache  and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be
  reclaimed  due  to  items  being  in  use  (MemAvailable   in
  /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels
  2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free)